# Workflow Reject by(worker/person) name in email template?

Tags: workflow, axapta, dynamics-ax-2012, x++

How can I take the worker/person name in an email template of workflow on rejection/approval notifications?

Comment: Search for the word 'placeholders' in the following [MSDN article](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg188988.aspx).  Maybe the worker name exists in the list provided?
Also, this is a more functional rather than technical question.  Try either the [Microsoft Dynamics AX Forum](https://community.dynamics.com/ax/f/33) or the [AX User Group](http://dynamicsuser.net/ax/f/11)

Comment: I checked all place holders available in the dropdown but there is no placeholder for the rejector/approval person.

Comment: [Same question](https://community.dynamics.com/ax/f/33/t/201138) in AX Community.